# Rebuilding Windows Server 2019 Boot

Tags: windows, boot, raid

I have a Windows 2019 Server that has been in service for about 8 months. It is an MSI 670P motherboard and implements a RAID10. It won't boot.  Apparently there was a power failure, and the system would boot into Windows recovery.

Apparently there was some effort to resolve the issue that resulted in it now not even booting to Windows Recovery.

I can boot from installation media, click "Install", load drivers at the partition window and it will see the raid drive and partitions.  I then exited the "Install" and click on "Repair" and can see the files from the command prompt. Chkdsk says all is well. Data looks good, and I have copied it all off (I hope).

So now I'm trying to figure out how the devil to get this baby to boot.  I will freely admit the BCD boot process is unclear to me, so how to get the system to boot to what otherwise looks like a perfectly fine windows partition is beyond me.  I did try bootrec /fixboot and /fixmbr.  No joy.

I'm assuming the EFI partition needs to be bootable, and somehow must be configured to boot the windows OS, but the ugly details are beyond me.

Googling has only confused me more. Has anyone ever done this before? If so, is there a process and my googling just isn't working for me?

Comment: Recovering a RAID is not simple, and you need to give much more details about your OS, RAID type and whether it is hardware or software.

Comment: What else? The motherboard model is provided, the raid is implemented via the motherboard is included, and the operating system is specified as Windows Server 2019.  That seems to address what you say I need to specify.